# Can't make migrations

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I write `python3 manage.py makemigrations` (I have a mac), migrations are not done, I get a lot of errors, but I don't understand anything about the project at all, here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/ims/settings.py", line 35, in <module>
    hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

**ims/api/ims/settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for ims project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import socket

import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'mysecretkey')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_HOSTS', 'example.com').split(',')

INTERNAL_IPS = os.environ.get('INTERNAL_IPS', '127.0.0.1').split(',')

hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
INTERNAL_IPS += [ip[:-1] + "1" for ip in ips]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Locale apps
    'clients',
    'companies',
    'loyalty',
    'personnel',
    'products',
    'shops',
    'trades',

    # Third party apps
    'corsheaders',
    'django_filters',
    'djoser',
    'gtin_fields',
    'mptt',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',

    # Django modules
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_currentuser.middleware.ThreadLocalUserMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ims.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ims/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ims.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('DATABASE_POST'),
    }
}

# MIGRATIONS
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#migration-modules

MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'sites': 'sites.migrations',
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

if not DEBUG:
    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'companies.User'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'

EMAIL_HOST = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST', 'example.com')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_USER', '')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', '')
EMAIL_PORT = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PORT', 25)
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USE_TLS', False)
EMAIL_USE_SSL = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USE_SSL', False)
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get('DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL', 'webmaster@example.com')

if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Sites
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/#enabling-the-sites-framework

SITE_ID = 1
SITE_NAME = os.environ.get('SITE_NAME', None)
SITE_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('SITE_DOMAIN', None)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ims/static')]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Sentry
# https://sentry.io/cryptoins-el/eplatform/getting-started/python-django/

SENTRY_DSN = os.environ.get('SENTRY_DSN', None)

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=SENTRY_DSN,
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()]
)

# Django REST Framework
# https://www.django-rest-framework.org/

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT': 'json',
}

# Django Cors Headers
# https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers#setup

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# Django Debug Toolbar
# https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar

if DEBUG:
    INSTALLED_APPS.append('debug_toolbar')
    MIDDLEWARE = ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware', *MIDDLEWARE]
    DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
        'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': lambda request: True,
    }

# djoser
# https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html

DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password-reset/{uid}/{token}',
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create_password_retype': 'ims.serializers.IMSUserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer',
        'user': 'companies.serializers.UserCustomSerializer'
    }
}
```

edited `/etc/hosts` file and repeated the `python3 manage.py makemigrations` command and I got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/work/Projects/ims/api/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders'
```

teamlead in the team did something like migrations and they were applied, now, after I added indexes to models.py, to optimize sql queries, I needed to make migrations, but it did not work, but the server started without migrations

I don’t know which files to show, because I don’t understand the code in the project, because I’m new to django, but I’m always in touch and will throw off any files that you need

Thank you!

Comment: please add the file `ims/api/ims/settings.py`

Comment: already added ..

Answer (score 0):

You have set the machine hostname in **etc/hosts** file

1. find the machine name (https://help.edovia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002865213-Finding-your-computer-s-hostname-or-IP-address)
2. edit /etc/hosts file

   `127.0.0.1  Naveens-MacBook-Pro.local` (where Naveens-MacBook-Pro is my machine name)

Above changes are for MAC machine.

Comment: 1 - the user through whom I work on the second Mac, this is not the main user, I want you to know

2 - yes I found the hostname of the computer, but I didn't quite understand what **/etc/hosts** you are talking about, how can I find it?

Comment: try opening file ` sudo vi /etc/hosts`

Comment: I edited as you said the `/etc/hosts` file and repeated the `python3 manage.py makemigrations` command and I got this error, you can look at the question, I edited it,
thank you!